Restore nodepad++ file after reinstall
I've reinstalled nodepad++ using the below command:

sudo snap remove notepad-plus-plus
 sudo snap install notepad-plus-plus

Then all of my unsaved files has been removed, how do I restore them?

Needs details. What version of Ubuntu are you using? Where were the files stored, what directory?

@DavidDE thanks for the reply, the ubuntu version I'm using is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, but
where is the files stored, I can't tell. Could you guide me to find that place? Sorry for this inconvenience.

Usually in the .snap directory in your home directory under the name of the app. Although it can be other directories as well. I do not use that app.
